# Named parameter in Salesforce connector Query Single Mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb

I want to use named parameter in where condition of Query Single Operation in Salesforce connector in Mule version 4. I tried the below configuration but its throwing error.

```
     <salesforce:query-single doc:name="Query single" doc:id="dcec29d2-e031-123-be05-4566777" config-ref="Salesforce_Config" target="userId">
            <salesforce:salesforce-query >select id from user where email:email</salesforce:salesforce-query>
            <salesforce:parameters ><![CDATA[#[output applicaton/java
---
{
    email : payload.email
}]]]></salesforce:parameters>
        </salesforce:query-single>
```

How to use the named parameter in salesforce connector in Mule 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
<salesforce:query-single doc:name="Query single" doc:id="dcec29d2-e031-123-be05-4566777" config-ref="Salesforce_Config" target="userId">
                <salesforce:salesforce-query >select id from user where email= ':email'</salesforce:salesforce-query>
                <salesforce:parameters ><![CDATA[#[output applicaton/java
    ---
    {
        "email" : payload.email
    }]]]></salesforce:parameters>
            </salesforce:query-single>
```